# Pitch, Yaw, Roll calculation confusion

Tags: opengl, math, trigonometry

I am reading the [this](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Camera) tutorial and I got a bit confused. Why is the x value changing with the pitch when the pitch is a rotation about the x axis.

```
direction.x = cos(glm::radians(pitch)) * cos(glm::radians(yaw));
direction.y = sin(glm::radians(pitch));
direction.z = cos(glm::radians(pitch)) * sin(glm::radians(yaw));
```

I get how the rest are changing, but not the `cos(glm::radians(pitch))` in `direction.x`. How come this is the case ?

Comment: It's the difference between global x and camera x.  Pitch and yaw reference the camera local coordinate system.  You need to transform that to the global coordinate system.

Comment: Although pitch has no effect on the horizontal component of direction, the output of these formulas is a **unit** vector (magnitude 1), so the horizontal component must be scaled down as pitch is increased.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your pitch seems to rotate around Z, not X.

Second, Euler angles are applied sequentially, in this case Yaw is applied first, then Pitch. So as you noticed, `yaw` does not affect Y axis, as expected. But once it is applied, pitch rotates around the new Z axis, instead of the original one. If you set yaw=0, you will see that `pitch` no longer affects `direction.z` (since it is always 0).